# Following untracked working tree files?

Tags: git, github

I am coming across an issue where I try to git pull to update the branches on my computer from the repo to my computer and I come across this issue.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: binaries/*
```

I created a .gitignore file to ignore this folder and it's contents when pushing and pulling to and from the repo, but I guess it's not working. What would be considered a best practice to fix this issue so it doesn't abort every time I try to git pull to update the branches? (Through the terminal)

Comment: You need to remove the folder/files from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to rename or move you files elsewhere, as git is trying to put a file at the exact same location.

Depending on how you manage your remote repo, you may also remove the files under `binaries/*` from the remote.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a .gitignore file to ignore this folder and it's contents when pushing and pulling to and from the repo ...

That's not what `.gitignore` means or does.  I'm fairly convinced that the *name* (i.e., "ignore") is the source of a lot of the confusion here, because files listed in `.gitignore` are not actually *ignored* at all.  Unfortunately, there is not actually a good name for what it does: calling it ".git-don't-keep-complaining-about-these-files-if-and-when-they-are-sometimes-untracked" is not exactly a [wieldy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wieldy) name.

First, let's start with Git's definition of an *untracked file:* A file is untracked if and only if it is not in the *index*.  The index has two more names: it is also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*.  This is because it plays a very big role in Git, so big that you have to be at least vaguely aware of it at all times.  In a way, it's actually more important than your work-tree, where you do all your work, because it's the source of *every new commit you make*.  Running `git commit` packages up whatever is in the index at that point, and uses that as the source tree snapshot.  (Hence the name *staging area:* you use `git add` to copy a file from the work-tree, overwriting the copy that's already in the index, so that the index one is updated, or "staged", for the new commit.)

Now, the root of the problem is that your *commits*—at least some of them—actually *contain the file*.  Remember, Git doesn't store *files*, it stores *commits*.  It's true that commits drag files around with them—this is more than half of the point of each commit—but the *unit of operation*, as it were, is one commit at a time.  The `git push` and `git fetch` commands transfer whole commits, never part of a commit.  (Running `git pull` just runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge`; it's actually the `git merge` step that is failing.)

If a commit contains a file, and you check out that commit, you also check out that file.  That copies the commit's version of the file into your index.  The checkout command means *Copy from commit to index, then from index to work-tree.*  Once the file is in your index, it is a *tracked* file—the opposite of an *untracked* file.  A tracked file is never ignored.

Let's pick one file path name as an example, e.g., `binaries/foo.exe`.

So, suppose you successfully check out some commit in which `binaries/foo.exe` exists.  Git therefore writes it into in your index as well as your work-tree: it is now *tracked*.  Suppose the next thing you do is to check out some *other* commit in which the file does *not* exist.  Git therefore *removes* `binaries/foo.exe` from your index and from your work-tree.  Now the file is not tracked, but it's also *not even there*, so we don't go around saying `binaries/foo.exe` is untracked, even though it's kind of true.

At this point, you don't *have* `binaries/foo.exe`, but perhaps your next step is to run a build process that *creates* `binaries/foo.exe`.  *Now* you have a `binaries/foo.exe` that is *in your work-tree but not in your index / staging-area.*  Now, I think, all humans will agree that `binaries;foo.exe` is *untracked;* and now Git will say—or perhaps we should say, *complain*—that `binaries/foo.exe` is untracked.

*Now* the contents of `.gitignore` files come into play: now that `binaries/foo.exe` exists in your *work-tree* but not in your *index*, Git will either keep complaining about it, or not.  You shut Git up by listing `binaries/foo.exe` or `binaries/*` in your `.gitignore`.  The file is still *untracked*, but now it is *also ignored*.

The other nice effect of listing `binaries/foo.exe` in `.gitignore` is that an "add everything" command like `git add .` will *skip* the untracked file, not adding it to the index, without complaining.  But if the file is already *in* the index for some reason, this nice effect goes away.  It's already tracked, and `.gitignore` has no effect.

You can *remove* the file from your index:

```
git rm binaries/foo.exe
```

This also removes it from your work-tree.  Now you can make a *new* commit, and since the new commit is made from whatever is in your index, the file is *not* in that commit.  The drawback is, of course, that this also removes it from your work-tree.

You can remove it from your index *and* leave it in your work-tree:

```
git rm --cached binaries/foo.exe
```

and now the next commit won't have the file, which is now an *untracked file* since it's in your work-tree but not in your index.  (It may or may not also be ignored.)  But none of these affect *existing* commits, or commits made by *other people* who *did not* remember to de-index the file.  If you `git fetch` other commits that *do* have the file, `git checkout` will want to put the file into your index and work-tree, overwriting your untracked file.

This also goes for `git merge`: if you have an untracked `binaries/foo.exe`, and the commit you're asking to merge *adds* a *new* `binaries/foo.exe`, Git needs to copy that file into your index and work-tree.  This will overwrite your existing untracked file.  This is where one last feature (or bug?) of `.gitignore` listings comes into play: *Sometimes*, but not always, listing a file in `.gitignore` makes Git feel free to *clobber* the file.  (One of the more maddening things about Git is that it is hard to pin down precisely when this is.)

Anyway, in general, the solution is to make sure that no file you want untracked-and-ignored ever goes into any commit.  If it already *has* gone into some commit(s), that file will be tracked whenever you check out one of those commits.  There is no good cure for this problem.  You can investigate "rewriting history" to replace commits that have the file with commits that don't; or you can just avoid using the commits that have the file.  When you come across such commits, you can move your untracked file out of the way, check out the commit (making the file tracked), *remove* the file and commit (making a new and improved commit that no longer has the file), then move the file back.  It's not fun, and it's not automatic, but it does work.

Comment: Thank you for such great detail and insight into Github it is much appreciated. I actually ended up adding every tracked file with git add --all and then committed it all and it has overwritten everything when it merged(to the best of my knowledge) and now the working tree is clean.